# how to enable and disable a dropdown list based on whether a radio button is checked or not through jstl in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, radio-button, jstl, html.dropdownlistfor

In jsp page I have two radio button,if I check a radio button then one dropdown list should be enabled and if I select another radio button then another drop down list should be enabled and first dropdown list should be disabled.If none of the radio buttons are selected then both the drop down should be disbaled. How to do it using or  tags of jstl.I tried in thsi way,but no results

```
<b>Select Status</b>
<p><input type="radio" name="val" value="Filling" id="Filling"> Filling</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="val" value="Stored" id="stored"> Stored</p>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${Filling}">
Select Reference:
<select name="ref_logtime" >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
Select Reference:
<select name="ref_logtime" >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

**EDIT-**
How to do it through javascript ,if it can't be done with jstl.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="val"]').click(function() {
       if($('input[name="val"]').is(':checked')) { 
           var radioValue = $("input[name='val']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue == "Filling"){
               $( "#Fill" ).prop( "disabled", false );
               $( "#stored" ).prop( "disabled", true );
            } else {
                $( "#Fill" ).prop( "disabled", true );
               $( "#stored" ).prop( "disabled", false );
            }
       }
    });
    });
</script>
</head>

</head>

<body>
<jsp:useBean id="obj"  class="ref_Database.Refernce_Database" />


<form method="post" action="All_Mps.jsp">
<b>Select Status</b>
<p><input type="radio" name="val" value="Filling" id="Filling"> Filling</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="val" value="Stored" id="stored"> Stored</p>


Select Reference:
<select name="ref_fill" id="Fill" disabled="disabled" >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

Select Reference:
<select name="ref_stored" id="stored" disabled="disabled" >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<br><br>
<b>Select Date to be compared</b><br>
<p>
```

Comment: Use javascript, since clicking radio button is browser event.

Comment: ok,but how to implement it in javascript also??

Comment: Write javascript function to get the value of radio button and check the value. If first one enable the first select box and vice versa

Comment: @VinothKrishnan,I will get the values by var x=document.getElementById("mySelect") ,but how to see whether it is checked or not??

Comment: `document.getElementById("mySelect").checked = true;`

Comment: I'm trying in this way- function makeDisable(){
    var x= document.getElementById("Filling").checked = true;
    var y=document.getElementById("Fill") where Fil is the id of drop down,Now I want to enable it ,but y.enable option is not coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73716/discussion-between-vinoth-krishnan-and-tiddi-rastogi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML use like this,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" />Female
<br />
<select id="mOptions" disabled="true">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">Shirt</option>
    <option value="2">Pant</option>
    <option value="3">dhoti</option>
</select>

<select id="fOptions" disabled="true">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="4">Saree</option>
    <option value="5">Bangle</option>
   <option value="6">handbag</option>
</select>
```

And in scripting i have used the [jQuery](https://jquery.com) library,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="gender"]').click(function() {
   if($('input[name="gender"]').is(':checked')) { 
       var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue == "m"){
           $( "#mOptions" ).prop( "disabled", false );
           $( "#fOptions" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        } else {
            $( "#mOptions" ).prop( "disabled", true );
           $( "#fOptions" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        }
   }
});
});
```

Please find the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b6t7vg38/5/) with this link

Comment: You have same id for one radio button and dropdown box. Id should be unique, and in your scenario change the radio button id.